# Issue in generating calendar event using zxing

Tags: android, calendar, barcode, qr-code, zxing

I tried to generate calendar event qr code using Google ZXing API but the image generated by it is not recognisable as an event. I used the same data format specified at different websites but it only creates qr code but not as a recognizable event. BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Concert DTSTART:20110912 DTEND:20110912 DESCRIPTION:Metallica concert END:VEVENT Please help me to understand what I am missing. Issue is only for calendar event.

```
   //  In content.java TYPE:

     public static final String CALENDAR = "CALENDAR_TYPE";

// QREncoder.java
       else if (type.equals(ContentsTmp.Type.CALENDAR)) {
           data = trim(data);
           if (data != null) 
          {


               enter code here
              contents = "BEGIN:VEVENT"+data+"END:VEVENT";
              displayContents = data;
              title = "CALENDAR";
           } 
      }
```

it will generate qr code, but when i scan image it show type=text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status for the more or less inofficial Calendar Event Type is "Unconfirmed, Unreleased, Possibilities". See the zxing doc for more [details](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#unconfirmed-unreleased-possibilities).

There are only a few QR code reader who do support this format, but the majority and the important ones do not support this format.

If you want to process those QR codes in your application you have to implement the logic yourself. 
But if you want to create QR Codes which can be scanned and converted to iCal Events by random QR Code scanners you are out of luck.